# Android close multiple pop-up windows

Tags: android, popup, dismiss

I know how to close a popup with button, but what I need to do, is to make a method that would close all popups, that haven't been closed yet when I need to.
I have a method `popup()` that I use for generating popups. I call it random number of times.

After that the user can close some of them, but when a certain button on main screen is pressed, i want to call my own method `closeAllPopups()`, and it should dismiss all of the ones that have not been dismissed yet.

Any idea how to implement this method? I would be very thankful.

R.layout.popup: is just an very simple relative layout, it is not important.

```
private void popup(){

               LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                       .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

               final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view,200,300); 
               popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, 0, 200, 300); //popupi x ja y pos

               Button btnDismiss = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.dismiss); 

               btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       popupWindow.dismiss(); 


                   }});
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try storing all the dialogs in ArrayList and then dismiss them by iterating over them .